# How to detect if system media player is playing music?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making music recommendation app and I want to gain information about music being played when app is running. In Windows 8/10 there is some kind of overlay for music players (the box appearing next to volume bar in top-left corner of the screen) and I am wondering if there is any way to retrieve information about file/song being played by an application using this overlay. Some kind of event?